# Swift 2 : Change navigation title on a view related to a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, navigationbar

I want to change the navigation's title of a view, which is related to a Tab Bar Controller, which is related to a Navigation Controller (see the picture)

I don't know how to do that.

With a basic view, I just need to do that in the ViewController.swift :`self.title="test"`

But here, this line changed the tab bar's title, but I want to change the navigation's title.

[Main.Storyboard :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlITX.png)

Answer (score 5):

Use need to use this property:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "someTitle"
```

Answer (score 5):

On Swift 3, in the UIViewController, override your viewDidAppear method and add this code snippet:

```
if let tabController = self.parent as? UITabBarController { 
    tabController.navigationItem.title = "My Title"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple best practices you should not have a tab bar controller contained inside of a navigation controller, rather you should have the view controller for each tab that requires one to be inside of it's own navigation controller.

There are various issues that can arise from having a tab bar controller contained within a navigation controller.

When implemented according to their standards you can set the title using self.title

> An app that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of view controller in the same user interface, **the tab bar controller always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers**.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

Embed UINavigationController in your storyboard and put:

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = "Nav title"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had difficulty to change a navigation bar title of a child view controller. The solution was:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Pickup Address"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3+

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationItem.title = "Title"
}
```